# Why results does not improve even after adding dice layer to fcn8s network?

Tags: neural-network, caffe, image-segmentation

I trained fcn8s model for gray images. What I did: 1)convert images to RGB (since fcn8s pre-trained model only accepts three channel images), 2)train model with fcn8s pre-trained model, 3) tackling imbalance class members by adding `Dice` layer. My problem is that once I add dice layer the results are not improving, but becomes worse than before adding dice layer. 
I am wondering I am doing a mistake in some place, so I need your expertise to guide me whether I am wrong?!!!

The following curve shows the dice fluctuation and learning curve:
[image]

It seems I am doing some mistakes in settings.

Why accuracy is such high and training loss is decreasing such fast? Is this normal?

I have not added any `droupout` layer after `fc6` and `fc7` layers. Is network facing `Vanishing Gradient`?

Why network is undersegmenting the target object even after adding dice loss layer? What can I do to improve the dice value to above 80% at least?

What do you suggest?
Your help is really appreaciated. Thanks